# How should I transition from ZedGraph to d3js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, software-design

I have an asp classic with vbscript application. When I click an image I change the window.location to a page with an onload function. The only purpose of this function is to make a post request to an aspx page passing some parameters that will be used to retrieve some info from the database and create a graph using ZedGraphs. Then, it will become an image and returned to the client with Response.write().

Now i need to modernize the graphs using d3js.

My approach was to create an nodejs app that will recieve the post request (replacing the aspx page). However, since I don't know d3js, I don't know if I can make the same approach of creating a graph using it on server-side and serving it to an asp classic cliente-side...

Please, help me create a strategy before crafting unnecessary code!

Comment: just curious but what is the goal of modernizing it?  What features is it lacking that can't be accomplished with AJAX?   And why d3js if you don't know how to use it?  What is it offering other than what appears to be an uphill task?   Again just curious of motives on something like this.